# Why won't my program work in python?

Tags: python-2.7

Hi I am 11 yrs old and I am teaching myself how to code. I set myself a  task to make a times table quiz that asks 10 questions and inputs random numbers. However, my code is not working and I do not know why. I am using python 2.7.5. This is my code:

```
print("Here is a quiz to test your knowledge")
print("")
print("Question 1")
import random
print random.randint(1,10)
print ("times")
import random
print random.randint(1,10)
answer = raw_input ("Make your choice: ")

if answer == ran1*ran2:
print "That is correct"
correct=correct +1
else:
print "That is incorrect!"
```

I can not spot why it is not working but I have not put a for loop in yet so it only asks 1 question. When I run it else is highlighted in red but I do not know why.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could it be that you forgot to indent the statements between `if` and `else`? The three lines `print "that is correct"`, `correct = correct + 1`, and `print "That is incorrect!"` should have four spaces in front of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python works without brackets. It is replaced by "spaces or tabs". And we import ONCE, the beginning.

This should work

```
import random

print("Here is a quiz to test your knowledge")
print("")
print("Question 1")
print random.randint(1,10)
print ("times")
print random.randint(1,10)
answer = raw_input ("Make your choice: ")

if answer == ran1*ran2:
  print "That is correct"
  correct=correct +1
else:
  print "That is incorrect!"
```